# Localization of the module of Kahler differential of a regular ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R$ be a regular local ring, and also an algebra of e.f.t over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero. The module of Kahler differentials $\Omega_{R/k}$ is free of rank $d=\dim R$. Let $p$ be a prime ideal of height one: $\dim R_p =1$. The ring $R_p$ is regular, therefore the module of the Kahler differentials $\Omega_{R_p/k}$ is free has rank one $\operatorname{rk} \Omega_{R_p/k}=\dim R_p=1$. From the other hand, Kahler differentials commute with the localization
$$
\Omega_{R_p/k} \cong (\Omega_{R/k})_p.
$$
But $(\Omega_{R/k})_p$ is a free $R_p$-module of rank $d$. Where is my mistake in this sophism?

Comment: You have to be careful with the base field: $\Omega_{R_p/k}$ is different from $\Omega_{R_p/k(p)}$; the difference is controlled by $\Omega_{k(p)/k}$, the dimension of which is the transcendence degree of $k(p)/k$, which here is $d-1$ since $p$ has height $1$.

Comment: But $k(p)$ is the residue field of $R_p$, how $R_p$ is a $k(p)$ algebra? Moreover, I don't see why localization changes the basic field.

Comment: Uh, I am sorry, I mixed up things. One rather needs to use the exact sequence associated to quotients. This relates $\Omega_{R_p/k}$ to $\Omega_{k(p)/k}$ and $m_p/m_p^2$, the tangent space of $R_p$. Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $k\subset k(t)=R$. Then $R$ satisfies your eft hypothesis, regular and  dimension is zero, but $\Omega^1_{R/k}$ is of rank one and not zero. So, be careful.

Comment: I get this: rank of the module of Kahler differential is not the dimension of the ring, but dimension plus tr.deg of the residue field.